# angular2 firebase from a provider not working

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a new project and added angularfire2:

```
npm install angularfire2 firebase --save
```

In app.module.ts I import the module and initialize it with:

```
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
...
imports: [
...
  AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseconfig)
```

I can then use it in my components with an import like this:

```
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';
...
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
  public af: AngularFire) {
  this._users = af.database.list('users').valueChanges();
}
```

and all is well.

But I want to move that database handling to a provider. So i create a provider, add the name to the app.module.ts providers[] and import it into my component:

```
constructor (constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
  public db: DataserviceProvider) {
  this._users = db.users().valueChanges();
}
```

where the provider looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataserviceProvider {
  private _users: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

  constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
    this._users = af.database.list('users').valueChanges();
  }
  users(): FirebaseListObservable<any[]> {
    return this._users;
  }
}
```

which then gives me a weird error:

```
compiler.es5.js:1694 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for DataserviceProvider: (?).
```

That error disappears when I remove the 'public af: AngularFire' from the constructor (but gives other errors in the component obviously).

I've been looking for hours and the generic version of that 'resolve' error seems to indicate a cyclic dependency. But however I look at it, I can't seem to find any cycles in this.. Any pointers greatly appreciated!

Comment: Refer https://codingthesmartway.com/building-an-angular-5-project-with-bootstrap-4-and-firebase/, this may help for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also try in this way:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database'; 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Component({
  selector: 'courses-list',
  templateUrl: 'courses-list.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class CoursesListComponent implements OnInit {
  coursesObservable: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.coursesObservable = this.getCourses('/courses');
  }
  getCourses(listPath): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.db.list(listPath).valueChanges();
  }
}
```

or for more information, you can visit the whole app in (angular2,5+firebase+bootsrap):
https://codingthesmartway.com/building-an-angular-5-project-with-bootstrap-4-and-firebase/

Comment: Curious! Just using AngularFireDatabase instead of AngularFire works fine, with FirebaseListObservables and all. Feels like a bug but maybe it's working as intended. The AngularFire docs don't mention a difference between component and provider use... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is how your `DataserviceProvider` should look

```
constructor(private af: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this._users = af.database.list('users');
}
users(): FirebaseListObservable<any[]> {
    return this._users.valueChanges();
}
```

and in your `component` just call

`this._users = db.users();`

Comment: that makes sense but unfortunately it still gives the same error. Seems it's a bug in AngularFire because when I use AngularFireDatabase instead works as expected!

Comment: oops that must be `AngularFireDatabase` i din't noticed it